# Using JsonUtility FromJson to deserialize JSON in Unity

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization

I'm having an issue while trying to read a Json string in unity.
I created Classes based on the json response im receiving
but im not able to deserialize this json
Where I did wrong, can anybody help?

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "isSuccess": true,
  "message": "Suggestion Found",
  "response": {
    "result": [
      {
        "OriginalWord": "goodboy",
        "suggests": [
          {
            "suggestWords": "good boy"
          },
          {
            "suggestWords": "Cordoba"
          },
          {
            "suggestWords": "Catawba"
          },
          {
            "suggestWords": "Catawba's"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My Classes

```
[Serializable]
public class Suggest
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string suggestWords { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string OriginalWord { get; set; }
    [SerializeField]
    public List<Suggest> suggests { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Response
{
    [SerializeField]
    public int status { get; set; }
    [SerializeField]
    public bool isSuccess { get; set; }
    [SerializeField]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [SerializeField]
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

Im Deserializing like this

```
Response response = JsonUtility.FromJson<Response>(jsonString);
```

Comment: If you would look into the [Unity Manual -> Script Serialization -> Serialization Rules](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) you could find yourself that a) every custom class needs to be attributed `[Serializable]` and b) properties are **not** serialized only fields -> remove all the `{get; set}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above every class there got to be `[System.Serializable]` this is because UnityEngine has its own implementation of `Serializable` so you got to indicate its the System's that you want to use rather then Unity's. You also dont need to have `[SerializeField]` since this is if you want to show the property in Unity's inspection window and since this will not go onto any gameobject you dont need this. You just got to make it public.

Also in the class `public class Response` if you want json to map correctly you wouldnt use `public List<Result> result { get; set; }`, it would have to be named `response` and it will have to be 1 object not a list. So you can create a class called `Results` and have it have a list variable called `result` and it will be a list of type `Result` (no s). and in the result it would have the `OriginalWord` and a list of Suggest called suggests

Moreover, you must have a constructor for each class for it to work. So it would look like this:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class Suggest
{
    public string suggestWords;
    public Suggest(string suggestWords)
    {
        this.suggestWords = suggestWords;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Result
{
    public string OriginalWord;
    public List<Suggest> suggests;

    public Result(string OriginalWord, List<Suggest> suggests)
    {
        this.OriginalWord = OriginalWord;
        this.suggests = suggests;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Results
{
    public List<Result> result;

    public Results(List<Result> result)
    {
        this.result = result;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Response
{
    public int status;
    public bool isSuccess;
    public string message;
    public Results response;

    public Response (int status, bool isSuccess, string message, Result response)
    {
        this.status = status;
        this.isSuccess = isSuccess;
        this.message = message;
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```